# Understanding just-in-time compiling in the context of a Shiny App

Tags: r, performance, function, compilation, shiny

I came across an interesting article by [*Noam Ross*](http://www.noamross.net/blog/2013/4/25/faster-talk.html) on improving R's performance. Noam makes the following suggestion concerning the just-in-time compilation:

> You can also enable just-in-time compiling in R, which will
>   automatically compile EVERY function the first time that it is run.
>   This will slow down R quite a bit at first, as each function must be
>   compiled before it is run the first time, but but then speed it up
>   later. Just add this to the start of your script
>
> ```
> library(compiler) 
> enableJIT(1)
> ```

## Shiny App

I would like to understand impact of this approach on a performance of Shiny App. Given the [*basic principles behind Shiny App architecture*](https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson5/):

> - The server.R script is run once, when you launch your app
> - The unnamed function inside shinyServer is run once each time a user visits your app
> - The R expressions inside render functions are run many times.
>     Shiny runs them once each time a user changes a widget.

### *Questions*

1. First a generic one, is it worthwhile to enable just-in-time compilation for a Shiny App?
2. If so, where the **`enableJIT(1)`** statement should be located? At the very top of the `server.R` file (assuming that compilation would be done once per app) or ***within*** the server function so it's executed at each instance?

Comment: This seems like an even more relevant question now that (as of R 3.4.0) the byte-code compiler is now enabled by default at its level 3. As you mentioned, functions that are rendered many times probably perform better with JIT compilation, but this might lead to an undesirable increase in initial page load time. Running a shiny app with and without the line `compiler::enableJIT(0)` and profiling gives results that I'm having difficulty interpreting one way or another based on the way `profvis` renders output. **Did you ever find any useful information on this question elsewhere?**

Comment: @MattSummersgill Thanks for showing the interest; I haven’t found much info elsewhere but I’m developing a view that specific nature of Shiny apps renders just-in-time compiling irrelevant, with exception of apps that are utilising same functions repeatedly and frequently any potential gain is not really noticeable.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up-- I wasn't able to identify a major difference in initial page load or re-render times either, perhaps this falls in the "maybe not worth spending too much time on" category of performance optimizations.